# Javascript form onsubmit always runs on refresh

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation

I'm having issues with form submit - somehow when user has not clicked submit button, upon refresh of the page, the validation is ran and the error message is shown on the page.

Anyone knows why onsubmit doesnt work here, and how do i only show the error on form submit?

HTML:

```
 <form action="#" method="POST" name="signupForm" class="ggForm" onsubmit="return validateSignupForm()">
   
<div class="email">
  <label for="emailBox">Email*:</label>
  <input type="email" name="custEmail" id="emailBox" placeholder="john.doe@gmail.com" required
pattern="^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" title="(The email entered is invalid)">
                </div>
   
   <!-- submit button below -->
   <div>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
   </div>

   <p id="potentialErrors"></p>
</form>
```

JS:

```
window.onload = init;

function init() {
  document.forms["signupForm"].onsubmit = validateSignupForm();
}

function validateSignupForm() {
    console.log("ran");
    var errMsg = "";

    var email = document.forms["signupForm"]["custEmail"].value;
    if (email == "") {
        errMsg += "<br>Email must be filled out";
    }

    // when there's errors in any field, put as message below submit button
    if (errMsg != "") {
        document.getElementById("potentialErrors").innerHTML = errMsg;

        //change the error message css
        $("p#potentialErrors").css("height","50"); 
        $("p#potentialErrors").attr("width","500"); 
        $("p#potentialErrors").css("font-weight","bold");
        $("p#potentialErrors").css("color","red"); 

        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Edit FYI: i have edited the above code into this codepen, it is working now:
https://codepen.io/vadevalor/pen/VwepxdY

1. need to add jquery library,
2. need to remove html validation
3. as per comments for this question, need to remove () in the js function

Comment: `.onsubmit = validateSignupForm()` executes `validateSignupForm` and assigns its return value to `.onsubmit`. Remove the `()` -> `.onsubmit = validateSignupForm`

Comment: I think should be like: document.forms["signupForm"].onsubmit = validateSignupForm;

Comment: Don't change the question in a way that its content doesn't match its title. And if the change happens because of a comment then ping the author of that comment so he/she can react on that change (e.g. by removing a close/down vote)

Comment: @Andreas & Jon thanks both. Noted on that, i will not change the question. Now the problem is with the error message not showing when i remove the (), do you happen to know why? is it because of html validation? do i need both?

Comment: I solved it! Thanks yall :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `onsubmit` in the form `event.preventDefault();`, next add jquery library to you code.

So:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form action="#" method="POST" name="signupForm" class="ggForm" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); return validateSignupForm()">
```

Comment: thanks! i solved it - jquery was why the css wasnt showing, but more so its cuz of html validation and calling function with ().